# stopPropagation with jquery on a accordion header

Tags: jquery, html, stoppropagation

I'm trying to get a checkbox to work correctly within a according header (including the click event), i've found an example on how to do this with an older version of jquery (version 1.6.3) at http://jsfiddle.net/CkL2r/1/ or the code is below;

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="#">Text <span id="id">More text <input type="checkbox"/></span></a></h3>
<div>content etc</div>
<h3><a href="#">Text <span id="id">More text <input type="checkbox"/></span></a></h3>
<div>content etc</div>
```

​

```
$('#accordion').accordion();
$('#accordion input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

I just can't get it to work with newer version of jquery, i searched the jquery docs and as far as i can tell there shouldn't be any difference of this function between version.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which version are you trying to get it to work with? It works fine with 1.7.2

Comment: Works fine in 1.8.2: http://jsfiddle.net/NqYKw/

Comment: versions i'm using;       http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css, http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js, http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem was a trivial one..

When you select `jQuery 1.6.3` , you have a checkbox that says to include `jQueryUI library` in the fiddle.

But when you select `jQuery 1.8.2` you don't have the option. So you need to include that file **manually in the Add resources section.**

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CkL2r/207/)**

Comment: I've just added a resource (http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) and it still doesn't work. It does when using version version 1.7.0 like in the fiddle you provided.

Comment: You are adding the .css file.. What about the .js file ?? Check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CkL2r/207/